# The difference in Haskell function argument type declaration

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell.
I am just confused by the difference between the argument type declarations here:

```
someFunction :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool -> a
```

This will compile.

```
someFunction :: (Integral a, Bool b) => a -> b -> a
```

Yet given this, the compiler will complain:

> ```
> • Expecting one fewer arguments to ‘Bool’
>   Expected kind ‘* -> Constraint’, but ‘Bool’ has kind ‘*’
> • In the type signature:
>     someFunction :: (Integral a, Bool b) => a -> b -> a
> ```

What is the difference between the two declarations?  I tried to search with Google but it seems there is no direct answer to this one.

Thanks!

---

Thanks for the quick answers guys. And they lead me to the next question: what are the thoughts behind having argument constraints to be in different places in the declaration? (vs C-like languages where the constraints, abstract or concrete, are mixed together in the declaration)

Comment: `Integral` is a *type class*, whereas `Bool` is a *specific* type.

Comment: C-like languages do not usually have (Haskell-style) constraints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Integral` is not a type: it is a typeclass. It describes a constraint on a type.

So, the signature:

```
someFunction :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool -> a
```

means that *"As long as `a` is an instance of `Integral`, this function can work on it"*.

Your second example of  `(Integral a, Bool b) => a -> b -> a` does not make sense, because `Bool` is a type, not a typeclass.

What does it mean to be an instance of `Integral`? Well, it means that somewhere, someone has written, for some type, for instance `Int`:

```
instance Integral Int where
    -- (declarations here)
```

---

Here's an example of your own typeclass: `Sizeable`:

```
class Sizeable s where
    size :: s -> Int
```

We can see this as types which have an associated size, which is defined by the `size` function. So, we can add some instances:

```
instance Sizeable [a] where
    size = length

instance Sizeable (a,b) where
    size _ = 2

instance Sizeable (a,b,c) where
    size _ = 3
```

So, we could write the function:

```
sizePlusOne s = (size s) + 1
```

And this would have the type:

```
sizePlusOne :: (Sizeable s) => s -> Int
```

Comment: so in other words there is no real use case for someFunction :: (Integral a, Bool b), if I just want the 2nd argument to be a Bool type??  do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @ChenSturmweizen No, it's just nonsensical. If you want the 2nd argument to be a `Bool`, just write `Bool`.

Comment: Saying there's no real use case for `someFunction :: (Integral a, Bool b)` is like saying there's no real use case for a ladder that is chocolate meters long. It's a mismatch in domains and doesn't make sense. The problem is that `(Integral a, Bool b)` looks like a function signature in C-like languages, but it really has very little to do with that.

Answer (score 3):

The items on the left of the `=>` are **type constraints**. Haskell uses **type classes** for it. A type class is best seen as an *interface* in programming languages like Java, etc.

For instance in Haskell there is a class `Eq`:

> ```
> class Eq a where
>   (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
>   (/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
> ```

Now we can make a type `Int` a "*member*" of the `Num` typeclass, by declaring it an `instance` of `Num`, and **implement the functions that are part of the `class`. Say for instance we want to make the (positive) *Peano numbers* an instance of `Eq`, we then first define the Peano numbers as:

```
data Peano = Zero | Succ Peano
```

and now we can make it an instance of `Eq`:

```
instance Eq Peano where
    Zero == Zero = True
    s(x) == s(y) = x == y
    _ == _ = False

    Zero /= Zero = False
    s(x) /= s(y) = x /= y
    _ /= _ = True
```

So now we can compare two `Peano` instances with `==`, and `Peano` is registered as an instance of `Eq`. So that means that if we write something like:

```
someFunction :: Eq a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
someFunction x y z = x == y && y == z
```

then `a` can be `Peano`, since we require that `Eq Peano` (on the left side) holds.

Type classes are thus used to allow you to use *abstract* functions (like for instance `==` and `/=`), without knowing how these are defined for the concrete type.

`Bool` on the other hand is *not* a typeclass, it is a concrete type. So you can not write `Bool b`. It also makes no sense syntactically, since a type class *requires a parameter* (i.e. `Eq Peano`), whereas `Bool` is a type with no type parameter).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  My next question would be: what are the thoughts behind having argument constraints to be in different places in the declaration?  (vs C-like languages the constraints, abstract or concrete, are mixed in the declaration)

Comment: @ChenSturmweizen: type classes are more flexible. Some extensions also for instance allow multiple parameters, etc. For instance we can define a `class Convertible a b where convert :: a -> b`.

Comment: @ChenSturmweizen You could draw a very vague comparison with Java generics `<A extends Integral> A foo(A x, bool y)`. The correspondence is not exact, but at least should make it clear that we talking about type variables, with some constraint on them.

Comment: @chi actually this is exactly my question.  A more accurate comparison would be doing: foo(A x) <- bool y (this doesnt make sense syntactically in java  though).  Is any thought behind doing so?

Comment: @ChenSturmweizen I don't understand your example, what is it supposed to mean? (it isn't valid Java or Haskell).  Why is it more accurate than chi's analogy?